# How to find the sum of elements on even position?

Tags: c++

How to find the sum of elements on even position without usage of arrays etc, only normal operations?

For example:
159

Sum = 5.

159120

Sum = 5+1+0 = 6.

My work:

```
int sumofdigits(int x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(x > 0){
        if (x % 100 != 0)
            sum += x % 100;
        x /= 100;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: The number in the main function.

Comment: Not worthy for an answer: while(x) { x /= 10; sum += x % 10; X /= 10; }

Comment: Out of curiosity: just an exercise or do you actually need this for something practical?

Comment: That would be good for a string of numbers like BigInteger.

Comment: This is just an exercise.

Comment: The question is to add digits in even positions, starting from the left. Most answers are counting the digit positions starting from the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're counting "even" digits from the left, you first need to count the number of digits in order to know whether the least significant digit is even or not:

```
int sumOfEvenDigits(int x)
{
    // First, count the number of digits
    int digitCount = 0;
    int tmp = x;
    while(tmp) {
        tmp /= 10;
        digitCount++;
    }

    // If the number of digits is odd, throw away the least significant digit
    if(digitCount % 2 == 1)
        x /= 10;

    // Keep adding the least significant digit, and throwing away two digits until you're done.
    int sum = 0;
    while(x){
        sum += x % 10;
        x /= 100;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if the compiler already takes care of this but divisions are pretty expensive and you might want to replace (x /= 10) with (x *= 0.1), (x % 10) by ( x - 10*((int)(0.1*x)) ) and (x /= 100) by (x *= 0.01). Not as readable but can make a huge difference in performance if lets say you're performing this sumOfEvenDigits on a large number of integers stored in a database.

Comment: @nbilal Good point. This code is not optimized. If you need to perform this operation multiple times, it would be worth optimizing the loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
int accumulateIfEvenPos(int num, int pos) {
    if (num == 0) return 0;
    int digit = num % 10;
    int next = num / 10;
    return pos & 1 ? digit + accumulateIfOdd(next, ++pos) : accumulateIfOdd(next, ++pos);
}
```

You call it with pos 1 initially - demo [here](http://ideone.com/ljNszd).

Comment: Just tested and it doesn't seem to work.. for `159` it outputs `15` which is obviously wrong and for `159120` it outputs `16`.

Comment: @user3002211 oh, on even positions, I for some reason thought you were accumulating odd digits in the number, hold on

Comment: @user3002211 Recursive approaches are actually usually simpler to understand. Notice I simply extract the digit with num % 10 and then pass the remainder of the number (extracted by num / 10) for the very same process, keeping the result if and only if the position is even.

Answer (score 1):

Well simple modification should do the trick.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1549;
    //Get the number of digits
    int length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%i", x);
    int sum = 0;
    while(x > 0){
        if (x % 100 != 0) {
            //check if the number of digits is even to start from the last digit
            if (length % 2 == 0) {
                sum += x % 10;
                x /= 10; 
            }
            else {
                x /= 10;
                sum += x % 10;
            }

            x /= 10;
        }
    }
   cout << sum << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Solved the problem/bug in the algorithm. This might not be the best answer but I didn't want to completely write a different one(than the answer before edit).

Comment: Seems to work for `159`, it gives `5`, however for `159120`, it gives an answer `12` which is the sum of odd digits, not even..

Comment: @user3002211 I haven't tested but the problem seems to be that it starts from the back so it does {2+9+1} sorry, there are some other answers that should work.

Comment: @user3002211 It should work now. Basically, it checks if the number of digits is even, it starts from the last digit(0 in case of 159120). If it isn't even, it starts from the second to last (5 in case of 159)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have an index variable that keeps track of the position:

```
unsigned int digit_position = 0;
while (x > 0)  
{  
  unsigned int digit_value = x % 10;
  if (digit_position is even)
  {
     // Add digit_value to sum
  }
  // Shift value right one digit
  x /= 10;
  ++digit_position;
}
```

There may be other methods using a position variable and the `pow()` function.  But that is left as an exercise for the reader.